# Error creating a login using LDAP

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create a page with spring to authenticate using ldap. I followed the official guide but trying to connect to my active directory instead of a test code.

**AppApplication.java**

```
package CyndeaApp;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package CyndeaApp;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String index() {
      return "Weelcome to the home page!";
  }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
package CyndeaApp;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin();

}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=pharma").groupSearchBase("ou=Users").contextSource(contextSource())
            .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return  new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://192.168.1.210:389/"), "DC=pharma,DC=local");
}

}
```

**StackTrace**

```
    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0909AF, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839 ]; remaining name 'uid=sxv,ou=Cyndea'
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:206) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:85) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0909AF, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839; remaining name 'uid=sxv,ou=Cyndea'at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:820) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:803) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.retrieveEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:86) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:187) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0909AF, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate$1.executeWithContext(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:139) ~[spring-security-ldap-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:817) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I think the error is in the LDAP connection, but I think I have all the parameters fine. If you need more information please, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you jwilleke
Finally, I have managed to do LDAP authentication. 
I have completely changed the code of WebSecurityConfig that I found in the following [link](https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication-5ea04969f220). It works! in production environment

Answer (score 0):

Appears you do not have a "bind" to the Microsoft Active Directory server as shown by the entry"

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0909AF, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839
```

Microsoft Active Directory, by default settings, requires a bind for most operations.
-jim

Comment: In php should also be needed? Because in php I have a login screen that has not asked me to bind. Thanks for your help